# Warning in REVTeX 4.2 for references to an external document: "... has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one"

Tags: theorems, external-files, revtex, auxiliary-files, xr

First, I build the following external document, ExternalDoc.tex file, 3+ times.

```
\documentclass[prl,aps,10pt]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{External Doc}
\maketitle

\begin{lem} \label{AeqB}
$A = B$.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm} \label{CeqD}
$C = D$.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I then build the following MainDoc.tex 3+ times.

```
\documentclass[prl,aps,10pt]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[ED-]{ExternalDoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Main Doc}
\maketitle

... See Lem~\ref{ED-AeqB} and Thm~\ref{ED-CeqD} in External Doc.
\end{document}
```

However, the output of the final build contains the two warnings:

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{thm.0.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{lem.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Can these warnings be addressed and resolved?  (There are hundreds of them in my real document, and it is time-consuming to find the legitimate warnings among them.)

Comment: Try xr-hyper instead of xr.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks for the idea.  However there is no change in the two warnings for a direct substitution of xr-hyper for xr in the above example.  And there is also no change if I replace the \externaldocument line with \externaldocument[ED-][nocite]{ExternalDoc}[filepath], where filepath is the local path to ExternalDoc.aux.  (There is no .dvi file in my build.)  I'm not sure what else to try without more documentation for xr-hyper.

Comment: move the \externaldocument behind hyperref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Ulrike's comments, it worked for me to edit and reorganize the preamble of MainDoc.tex as follows:

```
\documentclass[prl,aps,10pt]{revtex4-2}

% load most packages here

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% add any other commands here

\externaldocument[ED-]{ExternalDoc}

\begin{document}
\title{Main Doc}
\maketitle

... See Lem~\ref{ED-AeqB} and Thm~\ref{ED-CeqD} in External Doc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to call a equation in the `ExternalDoc` from the `Main Doc`?

Comment: @rainman I'm also interested in this, did you find an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I did not. I ended up typing it by hand. Most importantly, I found that these referencings do not work in PRL's submission portal.